# How to show flow in storyboard in the following scenario

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I need to show UIVIew when i will swipeup on UIViewController in ios with animation like it is coming from that UIVIewController,and i need to place that UIVIew in specific portion in UIVIewController not to cover on entire area.But my problem is i need to create this one in storyboard,normally storyboard means its for showing over all project flow so ,how to do that in storyboard.Please help me as soon as possible.I am new to iphone development i can do by programatically but  i am not getting how to do with xib.

Thanks & Regards
Harshitha

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to look at custom View Controller transitions, introduced in iOS 7. There were a couple of WWDC 2013 sessions on this, including one called "Implementing Engaging UI"

The fact that you're using a storyboard doesn't matter, storyboards are just a way to define your view controllers and navigations via segues. If you're doing a custom animation, your View Controller still segues as normal, it just does so with a custom animation (instead of one of the stock ones, like a Navigation Controller "push" or the various Modal VC presentations), which you provide via an animation controller - an object that conforms to UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning.

Answer (score 0):

Storyboard, or XIB? They are different.

The simplest thing to do is probably to create your view and get it set up in it's final position inside the view controller. Hook up an outlet to your view in your view controller.

Note the Y coordinate of the view when it is at the location you want it. Then use the size inspector to change the y coordinate of the view to the bottom of the view. (768 for a landscape iPad app, 1024 for a portrait iPad app, etc.)

Then attach a swipe gesture recognizer to your VC's content view, and in action for the swipe gesture, use a UIView animation method (`animateWithDuration:animations:` or a similar method to move the view's frame.origin.y up to the y desired y coordinate.